# How to use BOTH theme and content-scripts in manifest.json Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, themes, content-script, manifest.json

I'm trying to make a chrome theme that has both stylistic features (in the manifest "theme" element) and a content script (in "content-scripts" element). I've encountered a strange error where the content script only runs when there is no "theme" element.

My content-script.js is just-

```
console.log("content-script.js");
```

When I format my manifest.json file like this with no "theme" element it works-

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Test",
   "version": "1.0",
   "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content-script.js"]
      }
   ]
}
```

But when I add even an empty theme element my content script does not run-

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Test",
   "version": "1.0",
   "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content-script.js"]
      }
   ],
   "theme": {}
}
```

Anyone know why this happens, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Not possible in Chrome. For Firefox there's a [theme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/theme) API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. In Chrome, **themes** and **extensions** are two different things.

A **theme** is a special kind of extension that changes the way the browser looks. Themes are packaged like regular **extensions**, but they don't contain JavaScript or HTML code.

That's why when you include the **"theme"** field in your manifest.json, your extension can't run any content scripts.

I'd recommend you check the [Regular Extension Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/) and also the [Theme Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/themes/) to see differences between each of them.

For Firefox, though, there is a [theme API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/theme) available.